# regex negative lookahead - exclude the exact word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to modify an identifier, and it has a certain first letter, and zero or more continue letters, and I want to exclude some reserved words.
For the example I'm using the same first and continue letters:

```
(?!(abstract|alignof|as|impl|in|let|mut))[a-z][a-z]*
```

so abstract|alignof|as|impl|in|let|mut are the words I don't want to match, the thing is, with this regex I cant match the word "letter" because of "let". it only matches "etter"

I also tried this:

```
(?!(abstract|alignof|as|impl|in|let|mut))\b[a-z][a-z]*\b
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
How can I exclude the exact word?

Thanks

Comment: Add `\b` for the words in look-ahead also. `(?!\b(abstract|alignof|as|impl|in|let|mut)\b)`

Comment: @nhahtdh: Please post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add word boundary check for the words in the look-ahead also:

```
(?!\b(abstract|alignof|as|impl|in|let|mut)\b)\b[a-z][a-z]*\b
```

Technically, the first `\b` is redundant, since `\b` is checked outside the look-ahead. Since word boundary and look-ahead assertions are *zero-length*, we can swap them around:

```
\b(?!(abstract|alignof|as|impl|in|let|mut)\b)[a-z][a-z]*\b
```